# Show Springboot validation results in Thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am getting started with Springboot and am unable to propagate validation results (errors) back to the thyme template. I have a typical setup: @Entity object, @Service, and @Repository. Here are the sections of my Controller and index template (and its form). UserVital, UserBlood, etc. are the data objects mapped to the DB tables using hibernate. Hope this information is enough for the members to point me in the right direction.

**Data Object**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ".....")
public class UserVital {

    @NotNull(message = "Height (Feet) cannot be null")
    @Range(min = 0, max = 15, message = "Height (Feet) must be greater than 0")
    @Column(name = "feet", nullable = false)
    private int heightInFeet;
.............
}
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String getUsers(Model model) {
        UserVital vital = new UserVital();
        UserGrithMeasurements grith = new UserGrithMeasurements();
        UserBloodChemistry blood = new UserBloodChemistry();
        List<Category> categories = categoryService.getAllCategories();
        model.addAttribute("categories", categories.get(0));
        model.addAttribute("vital", vital);
        model.addAttribute("grith", grith);
        model.addAttribute("blood", blood);
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addData(@Valid UserVital vital, BindingResult vitalValidationResult,
            @Valid UserGrithMeasurements grith, BindingResult grithValidationResult, @Valid UserBloodChemistry blood,
            BindingResult bloodValidationResult, Model model) {
        if (vitalValidationResult.hasErrors() || grithValidationResult.hasErrors()
                || bloodValidationResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "index";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("successMsg", "Details saved successfully!!");
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

**Thyme Form**

```
 <form class="tab-content" method="POST" th:action="@{/add}">
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="height" class="col-sm-2 control-label" th:text="#{height}"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
     <input type="number" class="form-control" id="feet" th:attr="placeholder=#{feet}"
        th:field="${vital.heightInFeet}">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
<label for="neck" class="col-sm-2 control-label" th:text="#{neck}"></label>
<div class="col-sm-2">
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="systolic" th:attr="placeholder=#{inches}"
     th:field="${grith.neck}">
<div class="col-sm-2">
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ldl" th:field="${blood.ldl}">
.....
</form>
```

**Question**: As you can see I have multiple BindingResult objects. Each BindingResult object holding the validation results of the respective data object (vitalValidationResult holds validation result of UserVital object vital, etc.). Now, how do I write "th:if" statements in the template that will allow me to check if there are any errors in the fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by encapsulating the required form fields in a div and then placing "th:object=${objectName}" in the div.

```
        <form >
        <div class="tab-pane active text-center" id="tab_1_1" th:object=${vital}>
    <div class="tab-pane active text-center" id="tab_1_2" th:object=${grith}>
</form>
```